# If a comment tells me to try something, should I only edit the result into the question, or also reply to the comment?

Tags: discussion

If a comment tells me to try something, should I only edit the result into the question, or also reply to the comment?

For example:

- [Why isn't lxterminal installed when installing lxde-core?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363357/why-isnt-lxterminal-installed-when-installing-lxde-core#comment645926_363357)

What I should do for that comment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding your question; I think it's this?

> If a comment tells me to try something, should I edit the result into the question, or reply to the comment?

You should do both. The question should be complete, readers shouldn't need to check the comments to get the whole story. However, the person who left a comment will get an alert if you leave a reply comment, so they'll know to check your updated question; otherwise they might forget to ever come back and reread it. If the other person is really on top of things, they'll flag both comments as obsolete once they come back, and we'll clean them up.